# Legend for multiple plots in python ( list)

Tags: python, list, plot, legend

Hey I'm trying to plot a list and getting correct legend with list that contains:
00 = {Series:(15,)}
.
.
.
14 = {Series:(15,)}

So for I have done:

```
for i in curr:
    plt.plot(i, label = 'id %s' %i)
    plt.xlabel('line')
    plt.ylabel('curr')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But when I do that i get  a really big Legend box with all the 15 values inside the series in the list.

Thanks in advance. Picture attached of the plot and the legend box.

[Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hncgR.png)

Comment: What do you want in the legend box? I didn't understand.

Comment: I just posted a image of the plot, Im just trying  to get legend of the whole plot as just 1 to 14  or just whatever text I use  with the %i.

Comment: I think you want to do `label = 'id {}'.format(i)`

Comment: Thanks  Anurag Reddy ,yes I did minor changes as well: 
 plt.plot(curr[i],label = 'id {}'.format(i)) 
and that worked.